# how to change NextJS root path page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using next js for my toy project.

if nextjs is requested url that is root path, It find page named index.js in the pages folder.

However, I want to show user the page named home.js, not index.js when they request root url.

How can I change it? I guess It can be resolve if I custom next js server. But I want to more simple way. Is it possible?

Comment: When a visitor requests `/`, do you want the URL in the browser to change to `/home`?

Comment: @nicoqh if possible, I don't want to change URL, but only show them  `/home` page. if it is impossible, I have to rediect to `/home` URL.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible without using a custom server, but the caveat is you have to use **experimental features** `redirects` or `rewrites` depending on how you want to build your `home.js` page.

For example if you want to just redirect the user to `/home` when they visit the root `/` path, you can define a redirect rule in `next.config.js` in the root dir of your project.

```js
// in next.config.js (should be located in the root of your project if not create one)
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    async redirects() {
      return [
        { source: '/', destination: '/home', permanent: true }, // a permanent redirect
      ];
    },
  },
};
```

However, if you plan to take your project to production I suggest using a custom server for now, make use of the `redirects` and `rewrites` features when they become available in stable branch.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. it is the simplest way.

Comment: Then you should mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a standard way, but here's what I did:
I cleared the content in my index.js, imported my home.js into it, then I rendered it as its content.